# Method synchronizes on an updated field

Tags: java

My java code looks like this:

```
class xHandler
{
    private Channel _channel;

    // Methods...

    void init()
    {
        _channel = new Channel(...);

        synchronized (_channel)
        {
            // Do some stuff here...e.g.
            _channel.send("...");
        }
    }
}
```

In other files(threads) I create instances of Channel and send stuff with the use of the object, but only in the init method mentioned above I need it to be sync'ed and no other thread should open a channel and send something during this period.

FindBugs gives me a warning called: Method synchronizes on an updated field

*This method synchronizes on an object referenced from a mutable field.
This is unlikely to have useful semantics, since different threads may be synchronizing on different objects.*

How can I get this issue right? Is it possible to trigger this issue easily with a simple test?

Comment: Your code is invalid - you can't declare a field within your `init` method... did you mean that to be a simple assignment?

Comment: Mutable field means that private Channel _channel is not final. Try setting the field final;

Comment: Thx Jon Skeet for the hint, I edited, now it should be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_channel = new Channel(...);
synchronized (_channel)
```

> I need it to be sync'ed and no other thread should open a channel and
>   send something during this period.

Seems like your code is not doing what you are thinking that it is doing. Since you are creating a new `Channel` object per `xHandler` instance, and acquiring this specific `Channel` lock, two threads may run concurrently.

1. xHandler instance 1 creates Channel instance 1 and acquires it's lock
2. xHandler instance 2 creates Channel instance 2 and acquires it's lock
3. Both run concurrently

What you really need to do is either:

1. Share the specific `Channel` object that you want to sync for multiple `xHandler` instances (Example: receive a instance of `Channel` on `xHandler` constructor and assign it to `_channel`, remove the `_channel = new Channel(...);` line and keep your sync code as it is).
2. Sync on `Channel.class` which will mean that two different instances of `xHandler` will never be able to use any `Channel` simultaneously.

Example of sharing a specific `Channel` for two different xHandlers:

```
class xHandler
{
    private final Channel _channel;

    public xHandler(Channel channel)
    {
        this._channel = channel  
    }

    // Methods...

    void init()
    {           
        synchronized (_channel)
        {
            // Do some stuff here...e.g.
            _channel.send("...");
        }
    }

            public static void main(String[] args) 
            {
                Channel myChannel = new Channel(...);
                xHandler xHand1 = new xHandler(myChannel);
                xHandler xHand2 = new xHandler(myChannel);
                // Code to create / start your threads. 
                // xHand1 and xHand2 will not use myChannel simultaneously  
            }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that `synchronized` is acquiring lock on an object and not on a variable!

Each invokation of this method will have a lock on a different object, so the synchronized block in here is actually redundant, since you modify it when you enter `init()`.
[so as the warning says, different threads are being synchronized on different objects].

What will happen if two threads will try to invoke `init()` concurrently? Both of them might enter the critical section at the same time, and this is what you are warned about.

To solve it, you might want to declare `_cahnnel` as `final`, and initialize it in the constructor, and not `init()`.

Answer (score 2):

You keep on creating a new lock every time the method is run. Thus you are negating the effects of locking. The lock will always allow new threads in because there will be no threads waiting on the newly created object (there could be every now and then through some `race condition`). Each thread basically has its own lock (instead of a shared lock).

Move `channel` outside of the method.